# I'm encountering an error about "Expr1000"

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Recently I've built a query that suppose to give me all of the following columns based on `INNER JOIN` with other table as common of `UserID`, and count them to give me the most common once:

```
SELECT PhonesTBL.OperatingSystem 
   and PhonesTBL.Memory 
   and PhonesTBL.BatterySize 
   and PhonesTBL.CameraQuality 
   and PhonesTBL.Processor 
   and PhonesTBL.ScreenSize 
   and PhonesTBL.PhoneType 
FROM
    PhonesTBL 
INNER JOIN 
    HistoryTBL ON PhonesTBL.PhoneID = HistoryTBL.PhoneID 
WHERE 
    UserID = {0} 
GROUP BY OperatingSystem 
     and Memory 
     and BatterySize 
     and CameraQuality 
     and Processor 
     and ScreenSize 
     and PhoneType 
ORDER BY
    Count(*) DESC
```

This query returns Expr1000.

Comment: You appear – `{0}` – to be using `String.format` to add parameters to your SQL. This leaves you open to a SQL Injection security vulnerability. Never do this, always use parameterised queries.

Comment: Well Richard, im doing this for school project and i dont mind by far from countering sql injection, thanks for the tip, i appreciate it.

Comment: Too many developers blindly copy from [so]:. Thus what you consider a quick test/learning project could have consequences.

Comment: A fair note, this is not a site for homework projects it's for building internet artifacts. Also as someone who hires developers regardless of the project one should always use a secure programming model no matter how small the project or it's intended use; get in the habit of programming correctly and it sticks with you. Best of luck!

Comment: Note that using parameterized SQL has benefits beyond security. It helps avoid conversion issues, and makes your code clearer. I heartily echo the comments so far, and encourage you to adopt parameterized queries straight away. I know it can seem like there's an awful lot to pick up when you're starting out, but this is one place where it's worth "doing the right thing" from the very start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `and` keyword in SQL performs a boolean and. Therefore both your projection (the select clause) and the group by clause are generating a single value.

I expect you want to have comma separated lists of expressions on each case

```
Select PhonesTBL.OperatingSystem,
  PhonesTBL.Memory,
  PhonesTBL.BatterySize,
  PhonesTBL.CameraQuality, 
  PhonesTBL.Processor,
  PhonesTBL.ScreenSize, 
  PhonesTBL.PhoneType
[…]
```

Comment: Aight, now it fixed my expr1000 problem, thank you, Ohad.